# Combining two elements python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations

I have a list created from data referred to as stations = []

which prints out as

```
 ['france', 'england', 'germany', 'china', 'paris', 'sydney', 'gold coast', 'canberra', 'perth', 'melbourne']
```

I also have another function x which when printed prints.

```
[0.0, 3043.004178666758, 21558.2996208357, 40246.748450913066, 40908.82213277263, 43786.0579097594, 67781.1426515405, 79693.11338661514, 65046.35819797423, 92804.01912347642]
```

I have two questions.

Firstly) is there a way to combine the two i.e so i can print a new list or function that prints

```
[france = 0.0, england = 3043.004, germany = 21558.2999] and so on
```

secondly can I create variables or lists or something such that france holds the value = 0.0 so that if 0.0 is produced later i can call france and any data in the france variable?

Answer (score 5):

Use `dict` with `zip`:

```
>>> lis1 = ['france', 'england', 'germany', 'china', 'paris', 'sydney', 'gold coast', 'canberra', 'perth', 'melbourne']
>>> lis2 = [0.0, 3043.004178666758, 21558.2996208357, 40246.748450913066, 40908.82213277263, 43786.0579097594, 67781.1426515405, 79693.11338661514, 65046.35819797423, 92804.01912347642]
>>> dic = dict(zip(lis1,lis2))
>>> dic 
{'canberra': 79693.11338661514,
 'china': 40246.748450913066,
 'england': 3043.004178666758,
 'france': 0.0,
 'germany': 21558.2996208357,
 'gold coast': 67781.1426515405,
 'melbourne': 92804.01912347642,
 'paris': 40908.82213277263,
 'perth': 65046.35819797423,
 'sydney': 43786.0579097594}

# Fetching values
>>> dic['france']
0.0
>>> dic['sydney']
43786.0579097594
```

Printing keys and values:

```
>>> for k,v in dic.iteritems():
        # k points to the key, and v points to the value
        if v < distance:
            print k,"is less than", distance
        else:    
            print k,"is greater than or equal to",distance
...         
england is greater than or equal to 1000
canberra is greater than or equal to 1000
paris is greater than or equal to 1000
france is less than 1000
melbourne is greater than or equal to 1000
germany is greater than or equal to 1000
sydney is greater than or equal to 1000
china is greater than or equal to 1000
gold coast is greater than or equal to 1000
perth is greater than or equal to 1000
```

Comment: how would i go about printing the dic as a whole?  is that possible like print all values at one

Comment: @user2430623 use `for` loop.

Comment: how so i dont understand the use of for loop in this context.

Comment: @user2430623 what do you want to print exactly. all keys and values?

Comment: yes all keys and values is what i want to print. Also if i have the value of 0.0 appear later in a code will it automatically link to france

Comment: @user2430623 In dictionary keys point to values, values don't point to keys. So if  you use `dic['france']` in your code then you'll get 0.0.

Comment: can this dic be used in an if statement to compare values. I.e if known distance = 1000 for v in dic:
    if v <= knowndistance:
        print v, "lessthan"
    else:
        print v, "greaterthan"

Comment: If im looking at extending this. For example I had population data for each dict item stored earlier in the code. ie france population = 1000000. Is there a way i can load that only for the dict items that are less than distance?

Comment: @user2430623 Your question is moving way away from your initial goal, I'd suggest you to create a new post instead of adding new details to this post repeatedly.

Comment: ok i will was just wondering if you could assist with that or if i should make a new question